# Pollard's p-1 - correct way to build M

Tags: number-theory, factoring, integers, cryptography

I need some help regarding one of the steps in Pollard's p-1.

What I understood: We are assuming that there exists $p$, a prime factor of $n$, such that $p-1$ is $B$-powersmooth for some $B$ (not $B$-smooth!) and that we're trying to build a number $M$ (to be used as an exponent) such that $(p-1)|M$. Most commonly this is done in two ways:

1. $M = B!$
2. $M = \prod {q^a} $, for all primes $q <= B$ and $a$ sufficiently large.

Let's focus on the second. My confusion comes from the value of a. Using the main assumption we made ($p-1$ is $B$-powersmooth) it seems clear that $a = \lfloor log_q{B} \rfloor$. However, some sources (including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm)) use $a = \lfloor log_q{n} \rfloor$. Since we can assume $n >> B$ this works too but makes $a$ unnecessarily large.

At first I thought it's just an error on Wikipedia and I made a correction, but I found several revisions in page history that change this both ways ($B$ to $n$ and back), with no real discussion, which makes me unsure. Can someone explain why $n$ makes more sense than $B$ here, or confirm that $n$ was just an error?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! The second version wants to find the factor also, if $p-1$ is divisible by a large prime power. Even if $p-1$ is $B$-smooth, it can be divisible by a prime power much larger than $B$.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure I understand your answer. Regarding smoothness, I looked at the algorithm statement from various sources and the condition is always "$B$-powersmooth" and not "$B$-smooth". I understand that a "$B$-smooth" number can have huge prime powers, but that's not the main focus of my question. Do you need me to rephrase some parts, if you didn't understand the original post?

Comment: I believe $B-smooth$ means that a number can easily be wrote as products of small prime powers